# Equivalent of ReplaceAll for Associations?

Tags: replacement, associations

Is there a nice (built-in) way to apply Replace-style rules to key-value pairs in an association? Something like

```
SomeFunction[<| "id" -> 3, "freq" -> 4 |>, "freq" -> #freq+1 &]
(* should produce <| "id" -> 3, "freq" -> 5 |> *)
```

This could also be used to add computed keys, like

```
SomeFunction[..., "density" -> #mass / #volume &]
```

This would be really useful when combining with `Query` and `Dataset`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding the same key to an `Association` will replace the previous value, which leads to this solution:

```
assoc = <| "id" -> 3, "freq" -> 4 |>;
<|#, "freq" -> #freq + 1|> &@assoc
(* <| "id" -> 3, "freq" -> 5 |> *)
```

The following alternatives also work:

```
assoc["freq"] = 5
assoc["freq"] = assoc["freq"] + 1
assoc["freq"] += 1
```

Comment: Neat. The really interesting part of this isn't that adding a key replaces an existing one, but that you can merge by putting the whole association inside another like `<|#, ...|>`.

Comment: Actually...is that even documented?

Comment: It's as if Association had a Flat attribute.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `KeySelect` to operate on keys that meet certain criteria.

```
assoc = <|"id" -> 3, "freq" -> 4, "fred" -> 2, "geeze" -> 1|>;
endsInD = KeySelect[assoc, StringMatchQ[#, __ ~~ "d"] &]
```

> <|"id" -> 3, "fred" -> 2|>

```
Merge[
 {assoc, #^2 &@endsInD},
 Last]
```

> <|"id" -> 9, "freq" -> 4, "fred" -> 4, "geeze" -> 1|>

Comment: It's cool that functions like `^` work on the association's values.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `AssociateTo` to change an existing `Association` which is already bound to a variable. The definition of your `SomeFunction` would then look like the following

```
SetAttributes[SomeFunction, {HoldFirst}];
SomeFunction[a_, func_] := AssociateTo[a, func[a]]
```

and you examples work like this

```
assoc=<|"id"->3,"freq"->4,"mass"->2,"volume"->5|>;
SomeFunction[assoc,"freq"->#freq+1&]
SomeFunction[assoc,"density"->#mass/#volume&]
(* <|id->3,freq->5,mass->2,volume->5|> *)
(* <|id->3,freq->5,mass->2,volume->5,density->2/5|> *)
```